# How to escape apostrophes of form data?

Tags: php, escaping

I'm trying to write a script that reads in a file with a bunch of definitions in it. The definitions are setup correctly, meaning they have apostrophes in place as needed. But I have to strip out the php control apostrophes (not the ones used for escaping text) so that only the text is displayed in the form.

The user may alter the text of one of the definitions so the script would read in the submitted form, make sure all of the apostrophes are escaped, if needed, and save it.

I've been working on this, off and on, for a month but I just can't figure out how to re-add the apostrophes. I'm hoping someone here can see a way around this.

The code below simulates the actual code, which is much larger, but the output illustrates the problem I am having. Most of the code is just simulating the actual code so it would be less to look at. The output of the code will look like as shown below. It shows the way the definitions appear in the file, how they appear to the user in the form and what is to be saved to disk, which is where I'm blocked. Can anyone offer suggestions on this?

ORIGNAL APPEARANCE

```
define('TEXT_A', 'Just Text');
define('TEXT_B', '\' leading slash');
define('TEXT_C', NAME);
```

DISPLAYED IN FORM

```
Just Text
\' leading slash
NAME
```

TO BE SAVED TO DISK

```
define('TEXT_A', Just Text);
define('TEXT_B', \' leading slash);
define('TEXT_C', NAME);
```

.

```
<?php
//BEGIN SIMULATION
$definesArray = array();      //simulate the file loaded in
$definesArray[] = "define('TEXT_A', 'Just Text');";
$definesArray[] = "define('TEXT_B', '\' leading slash');";
$definesArray[] = "define('TEXT_C', NAME);";

$textArray = $definesArray;

$first_apostrophe = 17;  //skip the first part of each line since the length is the same in each

$defineArray = array();
foreach ($textArray as $line) {
    $defineArray[] = substr($line, 0, $first_apostrophe);
}

echo 'ORIGNAL FORMAT<br>';
foreach ($textArray as $line) { echo $line . '<br>'; } 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($textArray); ++$i) {    
    $pos1 = '';
    for ($x = $first_apostrophe; $x < strlen($textArray[$i]); ++$x) {   
       if (empty($pos1) && $textArray[$i][$x] == "'") {
           $pos1 = $x;
           $x++;
           continue;
       } else if ($textArray[$i][$x] == "\\'") {    
           $x++;
           continue;
       } else if (! empty($pos1) && $textArray[$i][$x] == "'") {   
           if ($pos1 == $x || $textArray[$i][$x-1] == "\\") {
               $x++;
               continue;               
           }    
           $pos2 = $x;
           $textArray[$i] = substr($textArray[$i], $pos1 + 1, $pos2 - $pos1 -1);
           if (($pos = strpos($textArray[$i], ')')) !== FALSE) {
               $textArray[$i] = substr($textArray[$i], 0 , $pos);
           }
       }    
    }

    if (! is_numeric($pos1)) { 
        $textArray[$i] = substr($textArray[$i], 17);
        if (($pos = strpos($textArray[$i], ')')) !== FALSE) {
            $textArray[$i] = substr($textArray[$i], 0, $pos);
        }     
    }
} 

//ABOVE CODE IS JUST TO SIMULATE ACTUAL CODE

echo '<br>DISPLAYED IN FORM<br>';
foreach ($textArray as $line) { echo $line . '<br>'; }


echo '<br>TO BE SAVED TO DISK<br>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($defineArray); ++$i) { 
    echo sprintf("%s %s);", $defineArray[$i], $textArray[$i]) .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: How you escape characters depends on where you are putting the character, not on where they are coming from. Since you appear to be putting them in text nodes (not attribute values) in an HTML document: You wouldn't escape them at all. Your question appears to be an X-Y problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "where I am blocked"?  Running your code ,I get exactly the output you list as the intended output to save to disk. What is it doing incorrectly that you need to fix?

Comment: The output is what would be saved to disk and will fail in a php file. Apostrophes are needed for the start and end of a text block in a definition as well as in normal text. I need to be able to add the ones for control back in. I'm blocked because I can't figure out how to do this. I know how to programmatically add an apostrophe but I can't see how to add them at the correct places, like at the beginning of text in the TEXT_A line but not at the beginning of the TEXT_C line since that is a constant, not text. Maybe it isn't possible since there's no way to know one from the other?